# How to change the default headless browser to chrome in Cypress

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, electron, cypress, headless

I'm using cypress typescript test framework
When I call "npx cypress run" it runs all my tests in headless mode with Electron as the default browser.
But I want to run it in chrome or any other browser. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.If you want to run tests on for eg. chrome. you can use:

```
npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

2.If you want to run your tests in headless chrome you can use:

```
npx cypress run --headless --browser chrome
```

You can get the list of browsers that cypress supports from [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers)

Comment: Is there a way to specify default browser via configuration file?

Comment: @MostWanted not yet as per this issue - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6646

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to angular, you could also add it to your `project.json` run configuration:

`// project.json or angular.json`

```
"targets": {
   ...
   "e2e": {
     "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
     "options": {
       "cypressConfig": "apps/storybook-e2e/cypress.config.ts",
       "browser": "chrome", // <<------ this line
       "devServerTarget": "my-app:storybook",
       "testingType": "e2e"
     }
   }
 },
...
```